# Using FindControl to find the contents of an HTML control

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I've got this code in the code-behind on my page, which works perfectly fine for a repeater:

```
    protected void AcctAssnRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBRConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
         {                
           string str10 = ((HtmlInputText)e.Item.FindControl("txtFlgUpdatedOn")).Value;
         }
     }
```

I'm trying to do something similar on another page, but it is telling me that "item" isn't valid:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str10 = ((HtmlInputText)e.Item.FindControl("txtDtSentToCIS")).Value;
     }
```

I'm still a C# n00b, can anyone tell me how to reference the value inside this control?  Both pages have a runat="server" on the aspx side, so I would expect that there's a way to do it, I'm sure my syntax just needs adjusting.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a piece of the aspx.  Maybe I should note that it's all inside a Tab Control.

```
                <div style="width:430px;border:1px solid blue;float:left;">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="220px" style="float:left; margin-left: 19px" 
                    Width="410px">
                         <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="210px">BIL Name:</td>
                                <td width="200px"><asp:textbox id="txtCISName" runat="server"></asp:textbox></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td width="210px">Date Sent To BIL:</td>
                                <td width="200px"><input type="text" id="txtDtSentToCIS" class="datepicker" name="txtDtSentToCIS" runat="server" style="height: 14px; width: 70px" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="210px">BIL Sign Off Received:</td>
                                <td width="200px"><asp:DropDownList ID="cboCISSignOff" runat="server" Height="16px" 
                                        AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="chkCISSignOff_CheckedChanged">
                                   <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="210px"><asp:Label runat="server" Text="BIL Response:" ID="CISResp" /></td>
                                <td width="200px"><asp:textbox id="txtCISResponse" runat="server" 
                                        textmode="MultiLine" rows="9" Width="180px"></asp:textbox></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:Panel> 
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you show related aspx part?

Comment: Im pretty sure that your repeater does not actually need to open the connection each time.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Where is your btnSubmit located in aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the ID to reach the control. For ex. a textbox:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtDtSentToCIS" runat="server" />`

In your code behind you can do something as

`SomeMethod(this.txtDtSentToCIS.Text);`

or

`string enteredByUser = this.txtDtSentToCIS.Text;`

Comment: I actually had to use **this.txtDtSentToCIS.Value** (had to use Value as opposed to Text because it is an HTML control).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access repeater containing textbox(es) from outside the repeater, you may code like this:

Iterating the RepeaterItemCollection:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    TextBox txtDtSentToCIS = item.FindControl("txtDtSentToCIS") as TextBox;
}
```

Or simply accessing through indexer:

```
TextBox txtDtSentToCIS = Repeater1.Items[1].FindControl("txtDtSentToCIS") as TextBox;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp I would suggest that you use an asp Text box.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxName" runat="server" />
```

When the button is clicked and you OnClick method is called you can search for the text box by name and assign the text to your string.

```
string str10 = textBoxName.text;
```

You don't really need to use the find control unless that control is buried in another control like a grid view or login view.

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is that the FindControl method only works for the first control collection in this case the only control contained is "Panel3", try this:

```
var panel = e.Item.FindControl("Panel3") as Panel;
string str10 = ((HtmlInputText)panel.FindControl("txtFlgUpdatedOn")).Value;
```

Good luck